# what is the right lambda for this inner class

Tags: java, lambda, filter, filenames, inner-classes

I have following code:

```
  private List<String> searchFolder(File tempDirFile) {
            List<String> listFile;
            listFile = Arrays.asList(tempDirFile.list(new FilenameFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    return name.contains(type);
                }
            }));
            return listFile;
        }
```

SonarLint tells me to "Make this anonymous inner class a lambda". So this

> new FilenameFilter(){.....}

is supposed to be "converted" into a lambda. I looked up cases and scenarios, but wasn't able to find a solution for this specific case I have here.

Comment: A decent IDE can do this refactor automatically. Install IntelliJ

Comment: Just a hint: IntelliJ IDEA (and I suspect Eclipse as well) has a really nice feature where you can just ask the IDE to convert it. Put the cursor neer `new FilenameFilter()` and press CTRL-Enter. This is also useful for learning how these kinds of conversions are done.

Comment: Arrays.asList(tempDirFile.list((dir, name) -> name.contains(type)));

Comment: @JEY: feel free to post this as an answer.

Comment: thank you very much JEY. like how does this even work? there is no indicator that I use a FilenameFilter. EDIT: I found an option to convert into a lambda. Thanks to all of you

Comment: @EinMatt: the compiler knows because `File.list` takes a `FilenameFilter` as the argument. It's just trying to make your lambda conform to that interface and if it can, then it works (the precise rules are a bit arcane, because they handle quite a few corner cases, but that's the gist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requestedd by OP: FilenameFilter is a [FunctionalInterface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) it has only one abstract method and it can be implemented with a lambda that match its signature and java compiler will infer the type:

```java
Arrays.asList(tempDirFile.list((dir, name) -> name.contains(type)));
```

Edit: the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation is optional you can create lambda for any interface with only one abstract method even if not annotated with it.

Edit 2: More about lambda expression https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: `@FunctionalInterface` is similar to `@Override`: it's not required, but if it's present then the compiler will check if you adhere to the restrictions and complain if you don't.